# UWP: Audio media capture in a background task

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, background-task, mediacapture

I'm a new in UWP. I try to record audio from a background thread through MediaCapture API.

My code here:

```
public sealed class Recorder : IBackgroundTask
    {
        private BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral;
        private readonly MediaCapture mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

            MediaCaptureInitializationSettings settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings()
            {
                StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio,
            };
            await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);

            var profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.Auto);
            profile.Audio = AudioEncodingProperties.CreatePcm(16000, 1, 16);

            await StartRecordAsync(profile);

            _deferral.Complete();
        }

        private async Task StartRecordAsync(MediaEncodingProfile profile)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(Guid.NewGuid() + ".wav", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                await mediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(profile, storageFile);

                Task.Delay(10000).Wait();

                await mediaCapture.StopRecordAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

It records .wav files 10 seconds each, but when I play these files, I hear nothing. Each file is 310KB+, so it isn't 0 bytes. **Does somebody know why it would happen?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It records .wav files 10 seconds each, but when I play these files, I hear nothing. Each file is 310KB+, so it isn't 0 bytes. Does somebody know why it would happen?

I'm afraid you can't capture audio in the `BackgroundTask`. Derive from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture?view=winrt-19041).

> InitializeAsync should be called from the main UI thread of your app. Apps must handle app suspension or termination by properly cleaning up media capture resources. For information on shutting down the MediaCapture object properly

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Maybe do you know, AudioGraph.CreateAsync also should be called from the main UI?

Comment: The document does not declare this, you could try to use  `AudioGraph` in un-uithread.

Comment: Already tried, but it stucks in AudioGraph.CreateAsync...

Comment: Maybe do you know some API, that runs in background and records audio?